# Find the longest sequence of increasing numbers in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the following task: to find the largest sequence of increasing numbers in an array.

I'll give you an example : `2 3 4 1 50 2 3 4 5` will return the sequence of `2 3 4 5` - that is the largest sequence of increasing numbers in the given array.
Another one is : `5 -1 10 20 3 4` which will return `-1 10 20`.

If there are two equal sequences -for example `4 5 1 2 -1` which has the sequences  `4 5` and `1 2` the first sequence will be returned.

Below is my method

```
public static List<Integer> findLongestIncreasingSequence(int[] numbersToBeProcessed) {

        List<Integer> longestIncreasingSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> currentNumbersSequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersToBeProcessed.length; i++) {

            int currentNumber = numbersToBeProcessed[i];
            int nextNumber = 0;

            // checks if it is not the last number in the array
            if (i != numbersToBeProcessed.length - 1) {
                nextNumber = numbersToBeProcessed[i + 1];
            }
            currentNumbersSequence.add(currentNumber);
            //checks if the current sequence ends here(the next number is smaller or equal)
            //or if the array ends
            if (currentNumber >= nextNumber || i == numbersToBeProcessed.length - 1) {
                // checks if the current sequence is bigger
                if (currentNumbersSequence.size() > longestIncreasingSequence.size()) {
                    longestIncreasingSequence.clear();
                    longestIncreasingSequence.addAll(currentNumbersSequence);
                }
                //clear the current sequence so it can start all over again
                currentNumbersSequence.clear();
            }
        }

        return longestIncreasingSequence;
    }
```

Any feedback received on this method is more than welcome. The thing I dislike the most is the check I make for the last element in order to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: Barry has rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110497/finding-the-longest-sequence-of-increasing-numbers-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

> The thing I dislike the most is the check I make for the last element in order to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

So let's avoid that check. Let's structure our loop such that we're back-comparing. That is, instead of comparing index `i` to index `i+1`, we compare index `i` to index `i-1`. That way, if we start at 1, we'll always have a valid comparison - since otherwise our loop invariant would've triggered:

```
for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; ++i) {
    if (vals[i] > vals[i-1]) {
        // continuing this sequence
    }
    else {
        // start a new sequence, of length 1, from i
    }
}
```

No further checks against `vals.length` are necessary, once we handle the empty case. The rest of the algorithm involves just keeping track of a current running sequence and the best sequence so far, which you *could* do with a local `ArrayList<Integer>` but better to just do with a couple `int`s.

Comment: could you please have a look at the original post that I have updated after your remarks?

Comment: @pgerchev Code should not be updated in questions, I've reverted your changes.